# Graph Factorization Question

Tags: graph-theory

I learned that this is an accepted fact:
**A ($2n-2$)-regular graph on $2n$ vertices has a $1$-factorization**

Why is this true. Let $n = 3$. Then we are looking at a $4$ regular graph on $6$ vertices. We can organize the graph as a hexagon and for each vertex, we connect it to four other vertices, two immediately to the left and two immediately to the right. I can find some one factors of this graph, but I cannot find a one factorization of the graph. Can anyone explain why and how a $1$ factorization exists for this specific graph. (I was able to determine that this statement is true for $n \ge 7$ using a theorem on $r$ regular graphs with $r \ge \frac{12n}{7}$, where $n$ is the order)

Comment: "A $(2n-2)$-regular graph on $2n$ vertices has a $1$-factorization" is just another way of saying that "a complete graph on $2n$ vertices has a $1$-factorization".

Comment: @bof I haven’t studied graph theory in detail, but as far as I understand, “a complete graph on $2n$ vertices” is actually a $(2n-1)$ regular graph. You can also look at paulinho’s answer to see that the graphs in question are not complete graphs.

Comment: I didn't say that a $(2n-2)$-regular graph is a complete graph. However, each of the two statements in my first comment easily implies the other.

Comment: The easy direction: assume that every $(2n-2)$-regular graph on $2n$ vertices has a $1$-factorization. We want to show that a complete graph on $2n$ vertices has a $1$-factorization. Remove a complete matching ($1$-factor) from the complete graph. What remains is a $2n-2$-complete graph on $2n$ vertices, which has a $1$-factorization. That together with the $1$-factor you removed is a $1$-factorization of the complete graph.

Comment: The almost-as-easy direction: We know that a complete graph on $2n$ vertices has a $1$-factorization, and we want to prove that a $(2n-2)$-regular graph on $2n$ vertices has a $1$ factorization. A $(2n-2)$-regular graph on $2n$ vertices is the complement of a $1$-regular graph. The fact that a complete graph on $2n$ vertices has a $1$-factorization tells us that there is **some** $1$-regular graph on $2n$ vertices whose complement has a $1$-factorization. But all $1$-regular graphs on $2n$ vertices are isomorphic, so it follows that the complement of **every** $1$-regular graph on $2n$ verti

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: One-Factorization]

Here is your one-factorization (each color represents a different factor).

Comment: This is cool. The question made me search up some relevant graph theory concepts. What are some interesting things that depend on graph factorisations?

Comment: @BenjaminWang I’m not an expert, but one example could be if the vertices represent each player in a tournament, and edges are drawn between each pair of teams that need to play a match. Then if a one factorization exists, it’s possible to organize $k$ gamedays (where $k$ is the number of 1-factors) such that each game day every team plays one of the teams they had to, and at the end of the season every team has played every team they were assigned to play exactly once.